# Eclipse unknown java object

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm trying to bring some java files from a prior project into a new project (by copying and pasting them to the new project's directory through the file system and refreshing through Eclipse) and I keep getting this little blue question mark underneath the files I'm bringing in (which apparently means that the file is an unknown object).

(Here's an image of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU3S6.png)

For context, both of the projects have different functionalities. The old one responds to REST calls (for which a web.xml (which is also not recognized by Eclipse) was used) and this new one uses Hibernate.

How can I make Eclipse recognize files from the previous project?

Comment: AFAIK, this simply means that you haven't added these files to your version control system yet.

Comment: yes, I can agree with @JBNizet and if you want to make web.xml recognized you can configure the project's facets. For example add Dynamic web project and JPA to your facets (in project properties)

Answer (score 4):

That blue question mark just means that this file haven't been sent to your SCM yet (SVN, CVS, Git, etc).